# Express Checkout InContext - Paypal user address selector

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I may have missed it, but in `Sandbox` mode, it seems the user can't select from their **existing** Paypal (verified) addresses.

[image]

Is this just a bug in sandbox, or is this expected behavior (even in production)? That dropdown/select list is empty. Checking the sandbox account, each address provided is subsequently *added to the account* .

If this (bug) is actually documented, or if I missed something in setup/code, I'll delete this question. Thanks!

---

### Update:

In Sandbox, the issue is that:

1. the user is first presented with the above UI (which asks for an address).
2. After providing one, there will be a `change` link which behaves just like in Production where user can then choose from a list.
3. The list **isn't** presented *initially* (forces user to add/provide)

Answer (score 0):

Not with Paypal so I can't answer the *Sandbox* matter (bug or documented), but as shown below all is good in *Production* - user is provided with a `Change` link and a "drawer" is presented for user to select existing addresses:

[image: Production screen shot]

Hth those who are testing the In Context implementation...

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, it says "the merchant only ships within the united states", and the screen is used to **add** an address. Maybe check if your sandbox buyer's address is out of US, and then add a US address to the sandbox buyer account, and then try again.

Comment: Thank you, but nope, sandbox user has a bunch of US address. Each time the sandbox user adds an address it's scoped to US too..so not only does the user already have _existing US address_, user adds one _each time_..and _none_ of them are available to choose from. At the end of the day, Production is fine though so just fyi to anyone testing...Thanks again!

Comment: This is interesting. I have my local ENV on sandbox too but never had such an issue. Maybe it's specific to your settings / parameters, or maybe it's a bug only some people have encountered. :D

Comment: Yup, weird..and the sandbox user _can_ in fact _change and choose_ from all those addresses (prior and added) **after** providing one. It's just the **initial** screen that seems to be an issue....seems to not "know" sandbox user has a bunch of (valid) addresses....thanks!